# How I can transform `Iterable<? extends Integer> keys` to `List<Integer> keys`?

Tags: java

I found out how I can transform `Iterable<? extends Integer> keys` to `List<? extends Integer> keys`. You can do this by using [this method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#toList-java.lang.Iterable-). It looks like this:

```
Iterable<? extends Integer> keys = // my keys iterable
List<? extends Integer> res = IterableUtils.toList(keys);
```

But I still don't know how I can transform this `Iterable` to `List<Integer> res`, not to `List<? extends Integer> res`.

Comment: Can't you just do it yourself (like loop through `res` and cast)? Or better yet, instead of using their util, just loop through `keys` and just put it in `List<Integer> res`.

Comment: Well, _if_ `Integer` wasn't a final class `Iterable<? extends Integer>` could mean the iterable (and thus the list) could be typed to a subclass of `Integer`. In your case that doesn't make sense so why do you have `<? extends Integer>` in the first place?

Comment: Extending on my previous comment: assume you'd have `List<? extends Number>`. This could actually be a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Double>` etc. Casting that to `List<Number>` (which is basically what you'd want to do) would allow to add any type of number so you could end up adding a `Double` to a `List<Integer>`. The wildcard doesn't allow that (it doesn't allow you to add anything to such a list) so keeping the wildcard is actually a good thing.

Comment: As @null_awe suggested: `List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(); keys.forEach(res::add);` *(No cast needed)*